# Run something when USB device is plugged in doesn't work

Tags: linux, usb, udev, ubuntu

I made a script in /etc/udev/rules.d/local.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor=="b58e"}, SYSFS{idProduct=="9e84"}, ACTION=="add", RUN+="notify-send USB"
```

I then reload udev with

```
 sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

I've tried to remove everything but subsystem and run. I've tried the run '=' instead of '+=', I've tired ATTR instead of SYSFS. I tried "sudo service udev restart" and "sudo reload udev". I unplug the device, then plug it in again and it does not run the action. I tried renaming it 70-local.rules and changing permissions to a+x. I've tried changing 'subsystem' to 'bus'. I've tried setting run to be "/path/test.sh" which has the same command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not an expert and this isn't an answer, but I've found the following steps useful in identifying the appropriate attributes to trigger on:

1. Locate the device path using `udevadm`, `lsusb`, or `usb-devices`. I normally just use `lsusb` and let tab completion in my shell guide me. In my case, the path is `/dev/bus/usb/003/007`.
2. Use `udevadm` to identify the device attributes for rule writing. In my case, I used `udevadm info -a --attribute-walk --root --name=/dev/bus/usb/003/007`.
3. Write the rule and check that it's triggering. In my case, I'm just changing the device owner to user "stephen" and it's very easy for me to check if it's working by using `ls -l /dev/bus/usb/003/007`. My rule for this case looks like: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", OWNER="stephen"`. I have a similar rule that puzzled me for a little while because the subsystem was expecting `ATTRS` not `ATTR`, which is why I recommend walking the attributes. The rule in this latter case became: `SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", OWNER="stephen".

And, of course, `man udev` is always helpful. As you said, you should struggle to identify that your rule is triggering properly and may be best off just doing a quick ownership change on the device as I did for a first step. You can run into trouble with bad attributes or symbolic links sometimes and it's

Comment: It was ATTR for me and the udev rules specify that the RUN command takes a program file as input. It must be marked as executable and it must have the #! at the top if it's a interpreted. The group thing made realize it was working but the run was wrong. This finally worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> it does not run the action

No, it runs the action. The problem is that *it doesn't know where to send the notification*, since there's no notification framework running when udev starts. You will need to send a DBus message across the system bus and have a user daemon catch the message and post a notification instead.

Comment: Thanks. I changed file to contain just SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN="echo 1 > /tmp/foo". It doesn't seem to make the file though. I tried it with or without the SYSFS stuff.

Comment: Now it's echoing "1 > /tmp/foo".

Comment: I tried [SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN="touch /tmp/asdfg"] with variations of run [RUN="gimp"] [RUN="echo '1' > /tmp/foo"] reloaded every way possible. Still no luck. Udev says 'udev start/running, process 5038' on restart so I know it's running. Is there a way to confirm it's taking my config file or make it spit out errors if it can't parse them?